# Select parent row from same table when a child row is supplied

Tags: mysql, sql

```
"id"    "parent"    "name"
"1"     "0"         "Books"
"2"     "1"         "Crime Fiction"
"3"     "2"         "Death On the Nile"
```

From something like the above, how can I select the `name` of the parent row along with the name of the `child`. Here, the name of the child row will be supplied. I need to get the `name` of the parent.

**Desired output:**

```
@id = 3

Crime Fiction //This is the name of the parent row - in this case 2
     Death on the Nile // This is the name of the row who's id was supplied.
```

How is selecting inside the same table done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select parent.name, child.name
from your_table child
left join your_table parent on child.parent = parent.id
where child.id = 3
```

Comment: useful but when `child = 1` not found row.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.name, t2.name as parent_name from tablename t1 join tablename t2
on t1.id=t2.parent where t1.id=3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN p.name IS NULL THEN "???" ELSE p.name END) AS name 
FROM <your_table> c LEFT JOIN <your_table> p
ON c.parent = p.id
WHERE c.name = <yourname>
LIMIT 1;
```

This query will return the parent name for the given child name, or "???" if it could not find a parent.